# How to add selected numbers in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of numbers , and I want to add up the numbers, but I don't want to add all the numbers from the list, just the selected numbers, like the first three.

```
list = [2, 3, 7, 11, 15, 21]
for i in list:
   sum += i
```

My code obviously adds up all the numbers from the list. I've tried changing the for loop to in range(0,4) but that just added together numbers 0, 1, 2, 3 and not the numbers from my list. So how can I modify my code to add up the first three numbers from my list.

Answer (score 6):

You could slice your list...

```
list[0:3]
```

You could do it like...

```
sum(list[0:3])
```

It also [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14668890/31671) you don't need the start `0` there.

Comment: +1 for using the `sum()` builtin. No need to reinvent the wheel. That said, it might be worth noting `list` is a bad variable name, and you can leave out the first index when it's `0`.

Comment: @Lattyware Good point on the variable name, and I added the note about the optional `0`.

Comment: @alex And what if I want to add random numbers (not in sequence) from my list, like the first, second, fourth and sixth number.

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate through the first three elements of your list. You can do this using [*list slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/1907098)

```
total = 0
for i in lst[:3]:
    total += i
```

As a side note, don't name your variables `list` or `sum` as they will override the built in type/function and could cause problems down the track.

Comment: Didn't realise you could omit the `0`. Nice.